# Rails 4 and controller specific assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

How to include controller specific assets. I have such code in head of layout:

```
= javascript_include_tag "admin"
```

and this in body:

```
= javascript_include_tag params[:controller]
```

It works OK at developer mode, but not at production.
What is best pracise for this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add all the files to the precompile configuration of your app.

have a look at the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets